# Django Return redirect working for one view but not for the other

Tags: django, forms, redirect, return

I cannot understand why it is working in one instance but not the other. I am working with django and output in django template. The only difference between the views/functions are in the second one (the one that is not working) I update the field with time. Time updates, saves in the model and displays updated time correctly. It is just the redirect that is not working.

The working redirect code-

Template, this code takes me to the edit page. Name of the url is "update" -

```html
<td><a href="{% url 'update' i.id %}"><button>Edit</button></a></td>
```

The form on the dit page-

```html
{% block content %}
<div class="wrapper">
<h1 class="ok">Entry Form</h1>

    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        
      <input type="submit" value="submit">

    </form>
    
</div>  

    <br>
    
{% endblock content %}
```

url-

```html
path('update_entry/<str:pk>/', views.update, name = "update"),
```

And views.py-

```html
def update(request, pk):
    order=Bank1.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = Bank1Form(instance=order)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Bank1Form(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/bank1')
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'myapp/entry.html', context)
```

Now here is the non working code. Template, the line that takes me to the update page. Name of the url is "update_enter_workout.-

```html
<td><a href="{% url 'update_enter_workout' i.id %}"><button>Start Time</button></a></td>
```

Form on the Edit page. Didn't add the entire form since I only need to update the time from this page. Just the submit button.-

```html
{% block content %}

<a href="{% url 'index'%}"><Button>Close this page and go to Home</Button></a>
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1 class="ok">Start/End the set now?</h1>
    
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
           
           <input type="submit" value="YES!">
    
        </form>
        
    </div> 

{% endblock content %}
```

url-

```html
path('update_enter_workout/<str:pk>/', views.update_workout, name='update_enter_workout'),
```

Views.py-

```html
def update_workout(request, pk):
    order=WorkOut.objects.get(id=pk)
    form=WorkOutForm(instance=order)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=WorkOutForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        time=datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        WorkOut.objects.filter(id=pk).update(start=time)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/bank1')
            
    context={'form':form}

    return render(request, 'myapp/enter_workout.html', context)
```

As you can see they are written the same way, but in the second instance redirect is not working. Any idea what can be changed. It is so simple, couldn't even find a typo or simple mistake like that.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accepting `str` for id fields? Primary Keys are integers, not strings. You need to cast to an int path converter:

Instead of:

```py
path('update_enter_workout/<str:pk>/', views.update_workout, name='update_enter_workout'),
```

Use:

```py
path('update_enter_workout/<int:pk>/', views.update_workout, name='update_enter_workout'),
```

Comment: That's a correct side-pass of this problem but be aware that `class IntConverter` has regex  ` regex = '[0-9]+' ` and `class StringConverter` has regex `regex = '[^/]+'`. So, we need to be careful because some other URLs may fire, and you may not reach a specific view to converting str to int.

Comment: Yes possible, but it is assumed that the correct id is coming from the template.

Comment: Thank you for the answer guys but it didn't solve the problem. Like before, everything is working but it does not redirect. Also, in the first example (bank1) I did with str and it is still working and redirecting perfectly.

Comment: Can you show the paths and URLs used in urls.py file